# What's happening with all these title changes!?

Tags: discussion, editing

I'm Sam. I work at Stack Exchange HQ in NYC. As you may have noticed, I've been refining some titles to turn them into questions and better reflect the query posed. Don't hesitate to let me know if you've got an issue with any of my edits.

Thanks,

SB

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Although you answered your question in the question rather than creating an answer. And sign-offs are discouraged. <insert emoticon>